# Update fields for MySQL Insert ... On Duplicate Key Update

Tags: mysql, etl, on-duplicate-key

I have a somewhat long MySQL ETL statement where I am inserting 32 columns of data into a table.  This ETL statement is also utilizing UNION as a derived table.

My code is similar to this, as defined in the the MySQL reference manual:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a, b, ... "32 columns total")
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT a, b, ... FROM t2
        LEFT JOIN t3 on t2.id = t3.id
   UNION
   SELECT a, b, ... FROM t2
        RIGHT JOIN t3 on t2.id = t3.id
  ) AS dt
**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = b + c**;
```

The problem: When using 'On Duplicate Key Update' I am getting duplicate rows added to my destination table.  I suspect I don't have this last line of the code written correctly.

My question: Do I need to add *ALL* of the 32 columns from my table to this **'On Duplicate Key Update'** statement?  Or *ONLY* columns with data that might change?

Thanks in advance, I find this part of the MySQL reference manual confusing and their examples much more simplistic than my real-world scenario.  I've searched and could not find an answer or example that is similar to my situation.

Comment: The table needs ot have a unique index, and that needs to be one of the columns you're inserting into.

Comment: Otherwise, how is it supposed to know that the insert is a duplicate of something?

Comment: You can't get duplicate rows inserted if you have a unique index.

Comment: Yes, agreed, the destination table does have a unique index.  I set this up so the primary key is a composite index and is the only unique index.

Comment: Ah, good point @Barmar, yes that I agree with as well!  The first part of my primary index is an auto increment number. So the primary key is (auto-inc, r_id, t_id).  Maybe the index is more the issue?

Comment: You need something unique in the columns that you're inserting, so it knows that it's a duplicate and should be updated instead of inserted.

Comment: The auto-increment ID field won't do it by itself unless that's in the insert.

Comment: Instead of a composite index, make it two separate indexes.

Comment: Yeah, the auto-increment is definitely not in the insert.  I created this way because of the MySQL bug when two or more unique indexes are present ... https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Barmar, I appreciate the dialog!
Turns out that since I was trying to avoid this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58637
I tricked myself into creating a primary key that did not work as intended.  ;)  I had created a composite primary index which was composed of an (auto-increment number, r_id, t_id).  Since the auto-increment number was not part of my insert it was allowing the rows to duplicate.
I changed my table indexes so the Primary index is still the auto-increment number and there is a new Unique index which includes (r_id and t_id).  This seems to be working now.

I am still curious about part of my original question:  When creating the 'on duplicate key update' statement ... Do I *really* need to include each field that could change?  In other words ... Does the statement *only* evaluate the fields in this statement for changes?

Thanks again @Barmar!

This is my first ever question posted to stackoverflow so hopefully I followed protocol!

Comment: I have been testing this and 100% yes, *ALL* fields that get updated need to be included in the 'on duplicate key update' statement.